# How to prove that coefficients of Maclaurin series of $\arccos(1-2x)/\sqrt x$ decrease as polynomial degree increases?

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, polynomials, taylor-expansion

I can compute the Maclaurin expansion of $f(x) = \frac{\arccos(1-2x)}{\sqrt{x}}$, which is the Taylor expansion of $f(x)$ around $x=0$ using $f'(0)$, $f''(0)$ and so forth. But I noticed that the series expansion seems to have decreasing polynomial coefficients as polynomial degree increases- in other words, $f^{(k+1)}(0)/(k+1)! < f^{(k)}(0)/k!$. I find it difficult to prove this, despite its seemingly evident nature.

Can anyone suggest a proof strategy?

Comment: Could you show your computation of $f'(0)$?  I get $f'(0) = \infty$, $f''(0) = -\infty$, $f'''(0) = \infty$, ...

Comment: @EricTowers You are right. I was working with $\arccos(1-2x)/\sqrt x$, instead of $\arccos(1-2x)$, and later transform. Edited the question accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: Either way, there is a serious problem taking a two-sided limit of either function's difference quotient at $x = 0$.

Comment: $$
\frac{{\arccos (1 - 2x)}}{{\sqrt x }} = 2 + \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{2}{{4^n (2n + 1)}}\binom{2n}{n}x^n } 
$$

Comment: @Gary Greak thanks! How did you derive the result - asking for a strategy

Comment: Note that $$
\frac{{\arccos (1 - 2x)}}{{\sqrt x }} = \frac{1}{{\sqrt x }}\int_0^x {\frac{1}{{\sqrt t }}\frac{1}{{\sqrt {1 - t} }}{\rm d}t} 
$$ for $x> 0$. Expand $1/\sqrt{1-t}$ into a power series and integrate term-by-term.  [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient#Generating_function) will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*This was done before the edit of the question*

$$f(x)=\cos ^{-1}(1-2 x)\implies x=\frac{1-\cos[f(x)]}2=\text{hav}[f(x)]$$ where appears the [haversine function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Versine#Haversine) which is one of the many trigonometric functions (have also a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula)).

So, basically, you are looking for the Taylor expansion of its inverse. Looking [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseHaversine.html)
$$\text{hav}^{-1}(z)=2 \sin ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{z}\right)$$ and everything becomes simpler
$$\text{hav}^{-1}(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{ \binom{2 n}{n} }{2^{2 n-1}(2 n+1)}x^{n+\frac{1}{2}}$$

$$a_n=\frac{ \binom{2 n}{n} }{2^{2 n-1}(2 n+1)}\implies \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{(2 n+1)^2}{2(2 n^2+5 n+3)}=1-\frac{6 n+5}{2(2 n^2+5 n+3)}$$

Comment: But the edit was done 19 hours ago and you submitted your answer 15 mins ago. Were you preparing the answer for more than 19 hours? :)

Comment: @Gary. My account was suspended during last week. When I saw the problem, I immediately thought about this trigonometric functions I learnt so lon time ago and .... never used before. Cheers :-)